# Qt4 layout in a groupbox

Tags: qt4

I am trying to make a `QGroupBox` to have the size of it's content, to fit the content.
I think I do not understand exactly how this works and I get in this strange situation:
I have 2 buttons in a horizontal layout and I placed this inside a `QGroupBox`. I added a slot to print debugging info when clicking a button (so the window is fully loaded when the debugging code is run).

The problem is that the `QGroupBox`'s `sizeHint` returns (-1,-1) but the horizontal layout inside the `QGroupBox` has a correct `sizeHint`. 
Any idea why the sizeHint in the `QGroupBox` is (-1,-1)? I think this problem causes all my other problems, because if the `sizeHint` is invalid then the `sizeConstraint` and `sizePolicy` will have no effect on the `QGroupBox`. I was expecting the parent widget to have a little larger `sizeHint` than the children layout.

The widgets and layouts are created with the Designer (maybe this is relevant, I have a complex interface so I must use the Designer).

*Update:* I looked at the code generated in the `setupUi` method and it seems that a intermediary widget is created, the layout with the buttons is placed on the widget and that widget is placed on the `QGroupBox`. I think this is for the feature that in the designer you can place a layout inside a widget and also can resize it.
Can I skip this widget when using the designer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

. I found the solution, in designer you can select the widgets you want layout and then click the layout in grid/form/horizontal etc button/menu . This option will create a invisible widget, put the selected widgets on the layout and set that layout to the invisible widget. To avoid this you cave to click the groupbox and hit the layout context menu and set the menu, this will align the widgets but the layout is not visible in the widgets tree.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this because you didn't actually [set the layout](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#setLayout) to your `QGroupBox` widget. See if adding the line below into your window constructor would solve the problem:

```
ui->groupBox->setLayout(ui->horizontalLayout);
```

where *groupBox* and *horizontalLayout* are `QGroupBox` and `QHBoxLayout` in question.

Comment: yes that is the cause but i needed a designer solution so i can see it working inside the designer,i am working on a comlex interface. I found the solution, in designer you can select the widgets you want layout and then  click the layout in grid/form/horizontal etc button/menu . This option will createw a invisible widget, put the selected widgets on the layout and set that layout to thje invisible widget. To avoid this you cave to click the groupbox and hit the layout context manu and set the menu, this will allign the widgets but the layout is not vizible in the widgets tree.